# What library to choose for machine learning on swift?

Tags: machine-learning

I have to do a ML project for university and I’ve chosen to do something similar as this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Aut32pR5PQA, since I have most experience with swift language, I would like to use some ML library for swift. I’ve googled and found this https://medium.com/@ricardocastellanos_13596/ios-machine-learning-libraries-and-frameworks-e458f18e5a18 but i have no experience with ML so I don’t know what to choose, what would be good option? Or should I start using python anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with Swift, your main option is [Swift for Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift). There are some tutorials in their web page (e.g. [this one for training a neural net on the Iris dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/site/tutorials/model_training_walkthrough.ipynb)).

I would suggest, however, to stay away from Swift if your main focus is machine learning. Swift for Tensorflow is one of the most popular ML libraries for Swift, and there are [rumors](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/f3b0v2/d_swift_for_modern_machine_learning/fhhrykj?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that it is no longer active. Other frameworks listed in the webpage you linked seem not to be active either, e.g. [Bender](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Bender)'s last commit was on January 2019, [SwiftAI](https://github.com/Swift-AI/Swift-AI) on May 2017, [BrainCore](https://github.com/alejandro-isaza/BrainCore) on March 2017. The same seems to apply to the Objective-C ones.

Python and R are the programming languages with most ML tooling available, so I suggest you go for one of them and use their vast and super active ML ecosystems.